# Execute code when scroll but each .5s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this situation when I use the mousewheel, but I dont want that this to happend instantly, like wait 50ms after I can increment i again.

```
var i = 0; 

function doSomething() {
  i += 1;
  console.log(i);
}
```

Need a waiting time till you can use mousewheel again.

Can someone show or explain the solution?

http://jsbin.com/lisozuyami/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle, it's quite difficult understanding what you mean when talking about scroll and just showing the increment part.

Comment: so, when you use mousewheel im adding 1 to the i variable, but its too fast, after one use of mousewheel i need a waiting time before you can add  1, hugeinc.com look here, you scroll one slide but you have to wait to scroll one again

Comment: If you're trying to stop the mousewheel from being used, then JS is unable to do that. If you want to execute some code .5 seconds after scrolling has stopped, then that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with timeouts (look at example). Or you can use some throttling/debouncing plugins like [this one](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)

```
var i = 0;

function doSomething() {
  i += 1;
  console.log(i);
}

var actionTimer = null;

function delayedHandling(){
  clearTimeout(actionTimer);
  actionTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething();
  }, 50);
}

$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
      delayedHandling();
    }
  })
  .on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
      delayedHandling();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use set time out function

**see this example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/nvgnqvzh/1/

or you can use [**.delay()**](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
setTimeout(function(){
 doSomething()
}, 50);
```